# Closed formula for Laguerre

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials, laguerre

Let $L^\alpha_n(x)$ be Laguerre polynomials of type $n$.
Assume $0<\beta<1$. Is there a closed formula for this sum
$$\sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{1}{(b+j)^{1-\beta}}L^{m}_j(x)$$

where $b>0$ and $m\in \Bbb N$

Comment: the series will not converge if $m\neq 0$.

Comment: why this series not converge

Comment: the terms decay as $j^{\beta-1}j^{m/2-1/4}$

Comment: Thank you @CarloBeenakker